# Como puedo unir, dos consultas en laravel. eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Intenté unir los usuarios que me dio en la primera consulta y filtrar de algún modo en la segunda consulta para que solo me de los posts de esos usuarios, y que en la vista solo recuperar la variable posts. Por que si en la vista hago un foreach de usuarios y después navego hasta los posts, me aparecerán por orden de usuario y no por orden de posts ¿De qué forma podria hacerlo?.

El método `whereReactedBy()` está en la documentación de Laravel Love, de esta forma puedo obtener los usuarios a los que sigo o realice la reacción de seguir, y después debo devolver a la vista los posts de dichos usuarios. Muchas gracias.

```
public function render()

{   
    $user=auth()->user();
    $users=User::query()->whereReactedBy($user,'Seguir')->get();


    return view('livewire.posts',[
    'posts' => Post::with('image','comments')
        ->orderBy('id','desc')
        ->withCount('comments')
        ->limit($this->loadAmount)->get()
        
    ]);


}
```

Comment: Te podría servir utilizar `whereIn()`. Imagino que en `Post` tienes al usuario, por ende sería `Post::with(...)->whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id'))->...`

Comment: @JonatanLavado Hola, Muchísimas gracias,  funciono perfecto, eres un crack. Feliz día. 